# PDF sharing web app with view/download statistics

Tags: web-apps, pdf, statistics

I have a PDF file and would like to share it for public view. I want to know the view or download number.

I have tried Mediafire, Dropbox, OneDrive, and Google Drive, none of these has this feature.

Is there any service that has this service available?

Comment: After asking this question, I read this question in SE Academia by chance: [Is it OK to present a URL using a link shortening service?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/is-it-ok-to-present-a-url-using-a-link-shortening-service/26299#26299). Considering if your documents are scientific papers.

Comment: Yep all my answers on Health SE got deleted because they contained too much quotes http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/211/what-to-do-when-a-question-is-precisely-answered-by-a-wikipedia-page-or-section Also comments keep getting deleting there, pretty arbitrarily, quite a few users have complained about it. It is the most hostile SE I have ever seen: downvotes, content deletion, plenty of complaints in meta, expert users leaving, etc. That's a pity as the topic is quite important.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt err, I'm afraid that you have post on a wrong site. Anyway, I believe all the problems are lying in here: [How do you define an answer?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/479/99). But I share your pain. It's really hurt :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net) is originally meant for presentations, but it can host PDF files.

You just upload your PDF file, and you get a public URL.
The PDF can be flipped online or downloaded.

The download number is visible just below the online viewer ([example](http://www.slideshare.net/NicolasRaoul/ecm-bi), uploaded in PDF format)

Also, I would argue that `http://www.slideshare.net/<user>/<filename>` looks safer to click than a shortened URL like `http://bit.ly/1nlLKJK`.

Comment: +1 for URL clarity, btw if you have any idea for [Getting URL in status-bar immediately on hovering over a link](http://superuser.com/q/778533/116475)... for PDF slides I like https://speakerdeck.com/ (e.g. https://speakerdeck.com/francky)

Comment: Btw, one issue with SlideShare is that we need to login to SlideShare to be able to download a PDF. I don't know whether we can change this when we upload a PDF, but I have some doubts.

Comment: FYI: [Browser extension to unroll shortened URLs (like http://bit.ly/1nlLKJK)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9965/903)

Comment: just find out that SlideShare does have detailed stats too.

Answer (score 8):

You can use some [URL shortener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) that have a click count such as https://bitly.com (free) or https://goo.gl/ (free), and shorten the URL to the PDF (which you can host anywhere) with it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice trick :D. I can explain what the contain is so not worry so much about how safe it look. Since Bitly gives me more statistic, I'll choose this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/):

- free
- example URL: http://www.scribd.com/doc/38873257/Knuth-1974-Structured-Programming-With-Go-to-Statements

[image]

- e.g. [my profile](http://www.scribd.com/Franck%20Dernoncourt)

[image]

- has some statistics:

[image]

but I stopped using them as they keep removing some of the documents I uploaded like RFCs or famous GNU FDL books. The "Scribd’s BookID copyright protection system" is fcking dumb and they won't change their mind:

[image]

Comment: its stats also not give much informative like Bitly

Comment: It isn't free anymore, I think they stopped doing that. Now they ask you for the money each time when you accessing some document. Unless you're a contributor.

Comment: No surprise I always had a bad feeling with scribd.

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2019 for Scribd

It has a simple stat panel:

[image]