# Google Chrome extension to unroll shortened URLs (like "http://bit.ly/Wxeieo")

Tags: chrome, url-shortening

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can unroll/expand [shortened URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) like `bit.ly/Wxeieo` that are present on a webpage.

E.g. it could expand the full URL when I [hover on it](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-revealer/nphhadgebjlmcfleikmiedhohdfbfoin):

[image]

By unroll/expand a shortened URLs I mean display the full final URL, e.g. `http://files.wiki4games.com/music/Francky%20de%20Paris%20-%20Mix%2081%20-%20Electro%20House%20(Void%2037)%20-%2001-07-2013.mp3` instead of `bit.ly/Wxeieo`. This would be useful to know what page I'm going to land on.

Comment: Do you have another solution? The tool you suggested no longer exists, and the other one doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

You can use [LinkPeelr](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkpeelr/ahhcmjnfhbpgagklnjhlcabnbcdgipje?hl=en):

- expands shortened URLs on hover
- works with most URL shorteners

[image]

- manually expand a shortened link on their [website](http://linkpeelr.appspot.com/):

[image]

Comment: Reviews indicate this extension may be suspicious, but I have not analyzed this extension myself.

Comment: It does seem like the extension isn't really maintained anymore, but it's source code is at GitHub: https://github.com/ibagrak/linkpeelr, if someone was curious. Seems like there is [some sort of survey code](https://github.com/ibagrak/linkpeelr/blob/ba9c7ad275975ed8e7f8c327654c2b36af735af6/chrome_extension/background.js#L25) that's been commented out

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LongURL](http://longurl.org/tools):

- free and open source
- can be used as a Firefox extension or Greasemonkey script:

[image]

- you can manually expand an URL by going on their [website](http://longurl.org/expand):

[image]

- support the most common URL shorteners: http://longurl.org/services

Comment: In case of Bitly, one can also expand it by adding a `+` at the end of the URL before visiting it. This trick opens the analytics page, showing the full URL.

Comment: This site is no longer online.